# Django: How to add other urls patterns from the same file in urls.py..?

Tags: django, django-urls

I've already seen the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs) and I am trying to do the same thing but it is not working. It is not matching the urls.

Here is my urls.py

```
profile_patterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^profile/$', views.profile),
    url(r'^thoughts/$', views.thoughts),
)

urlpatterns = patterns('',      
    url(r'^/user/(?P<username>\S+)/', include(profile_patterns)),

    # I also tried to do it this way.. But it isn't working.
    url(r'^abc/', include(patterns('', 
        url(r'^hello/$', views.profile)))),
```

I tried to access the following urls.

```
'http://<mysite>.com/user/<someUsername>/profile/'
'http://<mysite>.com/abc/hello/'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this `\w+` instead of `\S+` and not `''` but the path to user views:

```
profile_patterns = patterns('userapp.views',
  url(r'^profile/$', profile),
  url(r'^thoughts/$', thoughts),
) 

urlpatterns = patterns('',      
  url(r'^/user/(?P<username>\w+)/', include(profile_patterns)),
)
```